# Not able to fully mock RestHighLevelClient

Tags: java, elasticsearch, mockito, powermockito

I need to mock RestHighLevelClient to test my code. Basically when i call "search" method of RestHighLevelClient i get either UnfinishedStubbingException or WrongTypeOfReturnValue.

```
PowerMockito.doReturn(searchResponse).when(client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT));
```

this example throws UnfinishedStubbingException.

```
PowerMockito.when(client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT)).thenReturn(searchResponse);
```

this example throws WrongTypeOfReturnValue.

Here is my config

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(value = {
        RestHighLevelClient.class
...otherClasses
})
```

I googled about both exceptions but, i am not calling "mock.someMethod()" inside "thenReturn" method. Seems like every approach is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an open [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/40534) in elasticsearch repo. All I could do is the following:

```
@Mock
private RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;
@Before
public void setup() {
   restHighLevelClient = mock(RestHighLevelClient.class);
}
```

and then use it as follow

```
when(elasticClientHandler.createRestClient())
   .thenReturn(restHighLevelClient);
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap access to `RestHighLevelClient` in an abstraction. Use same signatures that `RestHighLevelClient` uses. Finally, mock the abstraction. Eg:

```java
public interface RestHighLevelClientWrapper {
    SearchResponse search(SearchRequest searchRequest, RequestOptions options) throws IOException;
}
```

```java
@Service
public class RestHighLevelClientWrapperImpl implements RestHighLevelClientWrapper {

    private final RestHighLevelClient client;

    @Autowired
    public RestHighLevelClientWrapperImpl(RestHighLevelClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public SearchResponse search(SearchRequest searchRequest, RequestOptions options) throws IOException {
        return client.search(searchRequest, options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to that [comment](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/31065#issuecomment-396360557) the best working solution is to create wrapping delegate service and mock it instead of mocking the whole `RestHighLevelClient` thing (I'm sure you are not using all of present methods)

Answer (score -1):

RestHighLevelClient can be mocked using PowerMockito. We can do like the following.

```
public class ElasticSearchService{

    private RestHighLevelClient client;

}


@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ ElasticSearchService.class, RestHighLevelClient.class,OtherClasses.. })
public class ElasticSearchServiceTest {
    RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient ;

@Before
    public void setup() {
        esInstance = new ElasticSearchService();
       
//Mock client here and set it to the instance of class to be tested
        restHighLevelClient = PowerMockito.mock(RestHighLevelClient.class);
        esInstance.setClient(restHighLevelClient);
}

}
```

Comment: Not a working solution.